# How can I configure Spring Boot 3 with Micrometer and Spring Stream (with RabbitMQ) that does not separate trace HTTP and MQ in Zipkin?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I configured a basic Spring Boot with Micrometer and Spring Stream (with RabbitMQ). I would like to configure that traceId can be passed into another service through Spring Stream.

I understand it loses trace info when I use tryNextEmit. So it will generate a new. I also understand, RabbitMQ messages get a "traceparent" header with "00-xxxxxx-xxx-01" new value.

So my question: How can I connect both traces that Spring Stream uses older trace information and one record appear in Zipkin?

Example code: https://github.com/Numichi/stackoverflow-question-micrometer-with-stream

Answer (score 2):

Use `StreamBridge` to send the message to Cloud Stream bindings instead of using Sink.
As you have mentioned, Sink does not allow Observation Context to propagate. I am not aware of any direct way of propagating the context when using sinks which will allow parent Observation to be passed down.

If you send message to Stream binding using `streambridge.send` then message to rabbitMQ comes under parent observation as expected and shown below
[image]